# Embedding Google V8 into ANSI C Application - where to start?

Tags: c99, v8, embedded-language, embedded-v8

I would like to embed a javascript engine into an ANSI C application.

In fact, I would like to be able to run some code entered on runtime, while being able to interact with some C variables and functions.

So, is V8 the only choice? Where should I start?

Comment: Why not something like Lua? There are several javascript engines, V8 is one of fastest, but not very portable. Other choices for JS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine#JavaScript_engines  If you want to interact with C, there is [Cint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cint) - C language embeddable interpreter.

Comment: Would you point me to LUA homepage (even with LMGIFY). Any experiences with spidermonkey?

Comment: "Lua homepage" -> first result (in google.com/ncr) "The Programming Language Lua http://www.lua.org/" (or use en.wikipedia.org). I think, huge (fast) JS engines are not so easy to integrate. I have not experience with this JS, but [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine) says that embedding of SpiderMonkey is easy.

Comment: yep, i was exactly at this page. Will try to compile it in in the evening. Wonder if c99 embedding will work. Thanks, osgx, you on habr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some "embedding quickstart" pages:

V8 JS Engine (WebKit):

https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started

https://developers.google.com/v8/embed

SpiderMonkey JS Engine (Firefox):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine

LUA: http://heavycoder.com/tutorials/lua_embed.php http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-embed-lua/

After quick looking into these links I think that V8 is more complex; both Lua and SM are easy to integrate into application. And to call C functions from SM or Lua you should write some wrapper code for every function.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what type of wrapper code we should be writing?

Comment: triple, start from https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started page. Wrapper is only needed if you want to call native (C) functions from JS code.